# What does it mean to "seed" a recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, terminology, recursion

I've encountered this term before, but can't find any description of what the term means.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=BSzUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=seeding%20recurrence%20relation&source=bl&ots=mBcSHDQvWc&sig=ziNYadfSgBokpjoROJE41YV2DxQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjF6tCgu7jZAhWE2VMKHRYoD5sQ6AEwBHoECAAQAQ#v=snippet&q=seeding&f=false) is a link to Berliner's book "Spin Labeling", and on page 50 is an example of the use of the term.

Comment: I can't find the term in the link you posted, but I'm sure I know what it means.  In a recurrence relation, each value is given in terms of some of the prior values, and you need enough of the initial values to get started.  It's like the initial data for a differential equation.

Comment: I see, so if you were doing a downward recursion, you would set $c^N$ = seed, then simply follow with c$^(n-1)$ = Ac$^n$, where A is the recursion relation?

Comment: No that's not what I mean at all.  If you have a recurrence like $x_n = ax_{n-1}+bx_{n-2},$ you can compute $x_n$ once you know $x_{n-1}$ and $x_{n-2},$ but you need a couple of initial values, say $x_0$ and $x_1$ to get started.  I think of  it as "priming the pump."

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of a downward recursion, then that would still work right?  In my original comment I had the recursive elements indexed in superscript, which I realize can be confused with powers

Comment: Your typesetting in the comment is not right which makes it confusing but I think what you are saying it right.
Seeding just means the initial values for a given recurrence. Changing the "seeds" will changes the sequence of numbers. This is common for pseudorandom number generation which is often generated with a recurrence relation. If you start with the same seed, you will end up with the same "random sequence". Different seeds will give you different random sequences.

Comment: To seed a recurrence relation, all that means is choosing an initial value for some "constants" or "terms" in the sequence or function's inputs.  Usually seeding is only seen used in relation to PRNG's or pseudo random number generators.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) uses the conventional term "initial values". Thus "seeding a recurrence relation" means to supply
initial values for the sequence defined by that recurrence relation
**and** with the initial values supplied. Both the recurrence
and the values are needed to uniquely define the sequence.

The use of "seed" as a verb (or noun) instead is not often used
except in certain contexts. Any first use of the term in a text
should include an explanation  of this term to avoid confusion.

As mentioned in a comment, it is very common in the context of
pseudorandom number generation where a recurrence may or may not be
used.